# How do you change the SSH port number?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, openssh

We just got a new router (Vodafone THG3000g) and it doesn't allow port forwarding for port 22. This means I can SSH in locally but can't do it remotely using the public ip.

I should be able to do port forwarding for a different port on the router, but how can I update the SSH settings on my Pi to do set this up? E.g. if i wanted to use port 2222.

Thanks

Comment: Type "ssh change port number" into your favorite search tool.

Comment: Yep, cheers for that. Was looking for an answer from the community I trust more than google. But well done for bringing the community down.

Comment: `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config` add a line with `Port 2222`. Save the file and restart the ssh daemon.

Comment: Although this is not the place for extended debate, *"bringing the community down"* includes asking a member of said community to take time to personally provide you with an answer to a question that must have been answered **thousands** of times already online.  Hooray!  If you have a few spare moments of your own, [this might be worth some of them](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/795/5538).

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a procedure to change the SSH default port to another port number like `2222`, check the SSH config file which is located on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

So, you would see `Port 22` that you can change it to `Port 2222`. Then, save the file and restart the SSH service:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: Thanks. After doing this and checking the status of the ssh service it says it's listening on Port 22 still - does that sound correct?

Comment: @lukenm My pleasure. Unfortunately, no, there was a mistake. Check [this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/109714/revisions) out to find out what has changed. -- You need to configure SSH by `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` not `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.